# MYSQL HELP - Order of Operations and Sub Query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, max, where-clause

There are two tables I am working with (ft_form_1 & ft_field_options).

**ft_form_1**

```
    submission_id  facility_id  admits  reporting_date    timestamp
    1              111A         1       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 17:53:17
    2              222B         3       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 18:42:20
    3              333C         6       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-03-31 19:27:47
    4              222B         0       2017-04-01 00:00  2017-04-01 18:12:12
    5              333C         4       2017-03-31 00:00  2017-04-01 19:38:25
    6              333C         5       2017-04-01 00:00  2017-04-01 20:31:16
```

**ft_field_options**

```
    list_id option_order    option_value    option_name
    1       4               111A            New York
    1       2               222B            Chicago
    1       1               333C            Boston
    1       3               444D            Miami
```

**What I am currently getting:**

```
    facility_id option_name option_order    admits  reporting_date      timestamp
    111A        New York    3               1       2017-03-31 00:00    2017-03-31 17:53:17
```

**What I want to get:**

```
    facility_id option_name option_order    admits  reporting_date      timestamp
    111A        New York    3               1       2017-03-31 00:00    2017-03-31 17:53:17
    222B        Chicago     2               3       2017-03-31 00:00    2017-03-31 18:42:20
    333C        Boston      1               4       2017-03-31 00:00    2017-04-01 19:38:25
```

With the below query, I am trying to get a list of all submissions from a specified 'reporting_date' for each 'facility_id' with a 'list_id' equal to 1. If multiple submissions are sent on the same 'reporting-date', only the submission with the most recent 'timestamp' will be shown.

**Problem:** I believe this query is not running in the order I'd like it to.  It seems the query is finding the max 'timestamp' for each 'facility_id' in the table and then filtering to only show submissions with a specified 'reporting_date'.  I'd like that to occur in reverse order - where the query filters to only show submissions with a specified 'reporting_date' and then narrows the list down to only show the max 'timestamp' for each 'facility_id. As you can see from my above example, Chicago and Boston are being left off the list because they have a more recent 'timestamp' on the following day.

I am a MYSQL newbie, so any help is appreciated!  I originally got the idea of the MAX subquery from this link: http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php

```
SELECT t1.facility_id, t1.admits, t1.reporting_date, t1.timestamp, 
t2.option_name, t2.option_order
FROM ft_form_1 t1
LEFT JOIN ft_field_options t2
ON (t1.facility_id = t2.option_value AND t2.list_id = 1)
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(t1.reporting_date,'%m/%d/%Y') = 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m/%d/%Y')) AND (timestamp=(
SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM ft_form_1
WHERE facility_id = t1.facility_id))
ORDER BY option_order ASC
```

*Imagine today is April 1st 2017 for the above query to work.

Comment: Your question and sample data are a bit messy and hard to follow.  Can you show us a clean input table along with the exact output you expect, based only the input shown?

Comment: if you add the date limitation into subquery as well, it should work as you expect. The subquery now searches max value throughout the table with only limitation being facility_id, it has nothing to do with order or execution.

Comment: Tim, I just cleaned up the formatting a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: @insider I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to use the *structured* part of *structured query language.*  SQL is a declarative, not procedural, language, so it can be confusing to think about the order in which it does things.

First, you are looking for rows with a list_id of 1.  Let's do a query to get that. Notice the use of `JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`: we don't want the unmatched elements. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bdc3c/1/0)

```
                  SELECT t1.* 
                    FROM ft_form_1 t1
                    JOIN ft_field_options t2 
                            ON t1.facility_id = t2.option_value 
                           AND t2.list_id = 1
```

Next we need to find the timestamp of the last submission on each reporting date for each facility. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bdc3c/3/0)

```
                  SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp,
                         reporting_date reporting_date,
                         facility_id 
                    FROM ft_form_1
                   GROUP BY reporting_date, facility_id
```

These kinds of subqueries are a good way to go, because they're pretty easy to test.

Finally, we join these two subqueries together to get what we want. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bdc3c/6/0)

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM (
                  SELECT t1.* 
                    FROM ft_form_1 t1
                    JOIN ft_field_options t2 
                            ON t1.facility_id = t2.option_value 
                           AND t2.list_id = 1
       ) a
  JOIN (
                  SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp,
                         reporting_date reporting_date,
                         facility_id 
                    FROM ft_form_1
                   GROUP BY reporting_date, facility_id
       ) b ON a.facility_id = b.facility_id
          AND a.timestamp = b.timestamp
          AND a.reporting_date = b.reporting_date
```

The trick is in the `GROUP BY` subquery, that finds the last timestamp for each reporting date.

Now, you have a submission_id in your table. If that submission_id is autoincrementing, then it's likely that the largest submission_id value for reporting data in each facility is the one you want.  **If that's true** you can simplify the query a whole lot.

This gets you the submission_id valued that correspond to the submissions you want

```
                SELECT MAX(submission_id)
                  FROM ft_form_1
                 GROUP BY reporting_date, facility_id
```

You can join that to your main tables like this, to get the result you want. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bdc3c/10/0)

```
 SELECT t1.* 
   FROM ft_form_1 t1
   JOIN ft_field_options t2 ON t1.facility_id = t2.option_value 
                           AND t2.list_id = 1
   JOIN (
                SELECT MAX(submission_id) submission_id
                  FROM ft_form_1
                 GROUP BY reporting_date, facility_id
        ) q ON t1.submission_id = q.submission_id
```

Comment: You should put in your own SELECT and ORDER BY clauses to get the exact columns you need.

Comment: Looks neat.  Where would I set the reporting date equal to a certain criteria such as = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m/%d/%Y') ?  Would I just add another AND down near the bottom?

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand what is going on below.  Why are the columns referenced twice without comma in between.  Sorry, slowly picking up mysql...  SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp,
                         reporting_date reporting_date,
                         facility_id